# How to set the selected items for a MagicSuggest box

Tags: jquery, magicsuggest

I have a jqgrid. When i select a row and click on the edit button, i open a form with all the various columns of that row. One of the columns is rendered as a magic suggest , which will load all the possible values from the db. So how do i set the selected item of that component to the one fetched from the row-column value? I can see all the possible values fetched from DB, but by default that component shows as nothing selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source http://nicolasbize.github.io/magicsuggest/

```
var yourObject=*something*;
$('yourSelect').setValue(yourObject);
$('yourSelect').addToSelection([yourObject], false);
```